# mysql log results shows correct answers but submit shows wrong answer

Tags: mysql

I am taking the earthhacker practice test for mysql. More versed in tsql so I'm wondering if I'm missing something from my code

```
SELECT format(max(totalsale),4 ) as 'max(totalsale)' from Sales;
```

Execute and test comes back indicating it's the correct answer but when I press submit I'm getting an error that says it's wrong. Is there something in the MySql code Im getting wrong?

[image: earthhacker mysql]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FORMAT()` function will return the results as a string. If the test is looking for a decimal response, you'll need to use `ROUND()` and *possibly* a `CAST()`:

```
SELECT ROUND(MAX(CAST(tmp.`totalsale` AS decimal(16,4))), 4) as `max(totalsales)`
  FROM (SELECT 100.66 as `totalsale` UNION ALL
        SELECT 250.00 as `totalsale` UNION ALL
        SELECT 249.99 as `totalsale` UNION ALL
        SELECT 175.43 as `totalsale`) tmp;
```

Returns: `250.0000` as a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is

```
SELECT ROUND(MAX(CAST(totalsale AS decimal(16,4))), 4) as 'max(totalsales)'
FROM ( 

SELECT  s.SALESPERSON, AVG(s.totalsale) as 'totalsale' 
from Sales s
GROUP BY  s.SALESPERSON
) 
;
```

I had to read the question again: Calculate the *highest* of the *average* sales.